# Enable Git-LFS on BitBucket Server using REST API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I need to interact programmatically with a BitBucket Server to create and manage repositories.

To create a repository, a [corresponding REST API method](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v815/api-group-project/#api-api-latest-projects-projectkey-repos-post) is available.

The created repositories should have LFS enabled. In the Web-UI, there is a simple checkbox to do this. But I was not able to find anything in the REST API to enable LFS programmatically.

Does anybody know of any API to enable LFS in a BitBucket repository?

I tried some variants in the API urls to see if there are undocumented methods (e.g. `...{repo-slug}/settings`, but wasn't successful (receiving http status code 405).